# Message driven beans with activemq-message consumption

Tags: performance, ejb, activemq-classic

Hi i have a j2ee application that process mails. Every time i receive an email the mail server puts it on an activemq queue. The web app has a message diven bean connected with the activemq queue to get the new mail. The problem is that the mdb consumes really slow about 20 mails/second the wildfly server is configured to have a mdb pool size of 500 and the mdb is configured with session max of 500. I have tested the activemq and a normal java application can consume messages much faster. Do you have faced this problem? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and found the following solution, in the message driven bean add the following:

@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)